# Regex to match only uppercase strings with or without numbers in specific format

Tags: python, regex, text

I have the following list of strings:

```
list1 = ['KVC Company','this is a sample', 'TEL 555-555-5555', 'DATE: 05/12/2021', 
'50 KG LOADER', 'COMPUTER SCIENCE', '13445556 AAA', 'MONDAY', 'AMT: 60', 'plenty', 
'data sources','USA 00000','EXM: J. Smith', 'X', 'FH']
```

I'm using the following regex to filter the list:

```
r'\b[A-Z]{3,}(?:\s+[A-Z]{3,})*\b.*$'
```

This regex matches all the strings that begin with uppercase letters but doesn't consider the rest of the letters.

I'm getting the output as follows,

```
output = ['KVC Company', 'TEL 555-555-5555', 'DATE: 05/12/2021', 'LOADER', 
'COMPUTER SCIENCE', 'AAA','MONDAY', 'AMT: 60', 'USA 00000','EXM: J. Smith']
```

My desired output is as shown below,

```
['50 KG LOADER', 'COMPUTER SCIENCE', 'MONDAY' ]
```

which contains only strings that are completely uppercase and doesn't have any **symbols** and have **only numbers not more than 2 digits**.

How can I filter out all other strings and return only string which are completely uppercase having only 2 digit numbers and doesn't have any symbols like `:,/,-` and lower case letters anywhere in the string.

Comment: If you care about every character, you don't want to use `.*`.

Comment: `^([A-Z]|\d)+$`  Something along these lines.

Comment: '50 KG LOADER' doesn't start with uppercase letter, can you be more specific ?

Comment: @ Scott Hunter goy u! but that doesn't match uppercase strings starts with digits

Comment: and why not `13445556 AAA` ? You rules aren't specific enough

Comment: @azro I only need all the letters to be uppercase even if it has digits anywhere

Comment: Why not `USA 00000`

Comment: Why did you exclude `'LOADER'` and `'AAA'`?

Comment: You could get those matches with `^(?=.*[A-Z]{4})[A-Z\d]+(?: [A-Z\d]+)*$` but then there should be at least 4 uppercase chars and not 3 https://regex101.com/r/coDqJv/1 or broader if there can be leading and trailing spaces `^(?=.*[A-Z]{4})[A-Z\d ]+$` https://regex101.com/r/W9v8gz/1

Comment: Or, `rx = re.compile(r'^(?!.*[a-z])[\w\s]*?\b[A-Z]{4,}\b[\w\s]*$')` and `print( [s for s in list1 if rx.search(s)] )`, see https://ideone.com/hFG0Lz

Comment: May be: `^(?!.*\d{3})(?=.*[A-Z]{3})[A-Z\d ]+$`

Comment: @PM77-1 AAA is not included since it has a prefix of numbers >2

Comment: @Thefourthbird Please sumbit it as a answer

Comment: @AnjaliA You have updated your question, in that case the answer of anubhava seems better as it takes the `not more than 2 digits` into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this regex in Python:

```sh
^(?!.*\d{3})(?=.*[A-Z]{3})[A-Z\d ]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBWozD/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*\d{3})`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have 3 digits anywhere
- `(?=.*[A-Z]{3})`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have at least 3 consecutive uppercase letters, somewhere
- `[A-Z\d ]+`: Match 1+ of uppercase letter or digit or space
- `$`: End